# Wierd unchecked conversion warning

Tags: java, interface, unchecked

I have used a Strategy pattern in my code, here is a short fragment:

```
public interface FindingStrategy<T> {
    Callable<T> setAction();
}

class FindSomething implements BindingActionStrategy {

...

    @Override
    public Callable<SomeObject> setAction() {
        return new Callable<SomeObject>() {
            @Override
            public SomeObject call() throws ... {
                return (SomeObject)binding.findSomething(somethingsId);
            }
        };
    }

...

}
```

Somewhere else i do:

```
 Callable<SomeObject> ts = (Callable<SomeObject>) strategy.setAction();
```

And compiler signals:

```
unchecked conversion warning 
required: Callable<SomeObject>
found:    Callable
```

What is weird, if I do this, there is no warning:

```
Callable<SomeObject> ts = new Callable<SomeObject>() {
            @Override
            public SomeObject call() throws ... {
                return (SomeObject)binding.findSomething(somethingsId);
            }
        };
```

How do I fix this? I tried to change a lot and I still get a warning. Please help!

Comment: What is the type of the `strategy` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the `strategy` variable has the generics type information, too.

The following will cause this warning:

```
FindingStrategy strategy;
```

while this should be fine:

```
FindingStrategy<SomeObject> strategy;
```

you shouldn't even need the cast then.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! You both helped me but since your answer was first I guess I should give you the "checkmark". I love StackOverflow!

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your class definition should read

```
class BindingFindingSomething implements FindingStrategy<SomeObject>
```